# Django v1.2 multi-db database debugging app?

Tags: django, django-database

anyone know if there's a django database debugging app which supports Django's multi-db API?

I used to use `django-debug-toolbar` but it doesn't support multiple databases and the [corresponding ticket](http://github.com/robhudson/django-debug-toolbar/issues#issue/71) is now open for 3 months.

Are there any alternatives worth looking at?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This has been on my list of things to do since before 1.2 came out but I've been swamped.  I'm not familiar with any work on the various branches of django-debug-toolbar that add this either.  And at present, I don't know of other tools that do it.

There's always the fallback of running this in a Python shell alongside runserver:

```
>>> from django.db import connections
>>> connections['my_db_alias'].queries
```

Comment: Thanks for answering. Unfortunately, I'm also extremely busy right now, but maybe I could help you out with a patch when I'm less absorbed.